# Number of epimorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be finite groups, and let $n$ be the number of epimorphisms (i.e. surjective hom.) from $G_1$ to $G_2$.

Then what is the number of epimorphisms from $G_1$ to $G_2$ with distinct kernels? How?

Comment: What is the context for this problem?

Comment: $n/|Aut(G_2)|$.

Comment: @ Steve : how ?

Comment: @William: try counting the number of epimorphisms with the same kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $\operatorname{Aut}(G_2)$ acts on the set $E(G_1,G_2)$ of epis $G_1\to G_2$. You are trying to count the orbits. The action is without fixed points, so there are $|E(G_1,G_2)|/|\operatorname{Aut}(G_2)|$. But I don't think you can expect to express this in terms of $n$ only!

Comment: In fact one can drop the finiteness assumption in the sense that if one knows that $n$ (the number of epimorphisms) is finite then $Aut(G_2)$ is finite as well and the final answer remains unchanged.